# Should Latitude, Longitude and Elevation have their own type in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, types

> For people interested in this topic: the accepted answer involves some concepts that I think are well described [here](http://joelburget.com/data-newtype-instance-class/). Namely, differences between `data`, `newtype` and `instance` keywords, and ways to use them.

---

I started to learn Haskell like a week ago (coming from Python and C#), and I want to implement a class `GeographicPosition`, that stores Latitude, Longitude and Elevation.

Specifically, I'd like to do it in the most elegant, functional, "unit-of-measurement" aware way.

If we take, for example, X, Y and Z in cartesian ("rectangular") space, they all mean the same thing, have the same range (from `-inf` to `+inf`), being orthogonal and uniform.

Now with Latitude, Longitude and Elevation this is not like that. Longitude, for example, is periodic, Latitude has some maximum rangess at the poles (which are themselves singularities), and the elevation has a minimum absolute value at the center of the earth (another singularity).

Singularities apart, it is obvious (to me at least) that they are not "the same thing", in the sense that X, Y and Z are "the same thing" in a cartesian system. I cannot simply flip the origin and pretend that Latitude is now Longitude in the way that I can pretend that X now is Y, and such.

So the question is:

> Should Latitude, Longitude and Elevation have their own numerical type in a type  representing geographical position in Haskell? What would be a good type signature for that (a minimal sample code would be great)

I would imagine something along like

```
data Position = Position { latitude :: Latitude,
                           longitude :: Longitude,
                           elevation :: Elevation }
```

instead of the more obvious, position-based

```
data Position = Position RealFloat RealFloat RealFloat
```

but I don't know which style is more advised. It seems like `Bounded` is an interesting construct too, but I didn't quite understood how to use it in this case.

Comment: When in doubt, make a new type.  In this case, you can use `newtype`s and smart constructors.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I personally would make a type for them, and if you really want to make sure to keep things within their periodic bounds then this is a great opportunity to ensure that.

Start by making simple `newtype` constructors:

```
newtype Latitude = Latitude Double deriving (Eq, Show, Ord)

newtype Longitude = Longitude Double deriving (Eq, Show, Ord)
```

Note that I didn't use `RealFloat`, because `RealFloat` is a typeclass, not a concrete type so it can't be used as a field to a constructor.  Next, write a function to normalize these values:

```
normalize :: Double -> Double -> Double
normalize upperBound x
    | x >  upperBound = normalize upperBound $ x - upperBound
    | x < -upperBound = normalize upperBound $ x + upperBound
    | otherwise       = x

normLat :: Latitude -> Latitude
normLat (Latitude x) = Latitude $ normalize 90 x

normLong :: Longitude -> Longitude
normLong (Longitude x) = Longitude $ normalize 180 x
```

(Note: This is not the most efficient solution, but I wanted to keep it simple for illustrative purposes)

And now you can use these to create "smart constructors".  This is essentially what the `Data.Ratio.Ratio` type does with the `%` function to ensure that you provide `Integral` arguments and reduce that fraction, and it doesn't export the actual data constructor `:%`.

```
mkLat :: Double -> Latitude
mkLat = normLat . Latitude

mkLong :: Double -> Longitude
mkLong = normLong . Longitude
```

These are the functions that you'd export from your module to ensure that no one misuses the `Latitude` and `Longitude` types.  Next, you can write instances like `Num` that call `normLat` and `normLong` internally:

```
instance Num Latitude where
    (Latitude x) + (Latitude y) = mkLat $ x + y
    (Latitude x) - (Latitude y) = mkLat $ x - y
    (Latitude x) * (Latitude y) = mkLat $ x * y
    negate (Latitude x) = Latitude $ negate x
    abs (Latitude x) = Latitude $ abs x
    signum (Latitude x) = Latitude $ signum x
    fromInteger = mkLat . fromInteger
```

And similarly for `Longitude`.

You can then safely perform arithmetic on `Latitude` and `Longitude` values without worrying about them ever going outside valid bounds, even if you're feeding them into functions from other libraries.  If this seems like boilerplate, it is.  Arguably, there are better ways to do this, but after a little bit of set up you have a consistent API that is harder to break.

---

One really nice feature implementing the `Num` typeclass gives you is the ability to convert integer literals to your custom types.  If you implement the `Fractional` class with its `fromRational` function, you'll get full numeric literals for your types.  Assuming you have both implemented properly, you can do things like

```
> 1 :: Latitude
Latitude 1.0
> 91 :: Latitude
Latitude 1.0
> 1234.5 :: Latitude
Latitude 64.5
```

Granted, you'll need to make sure that the `normalize` function is actually the one you want to use, there are different implementations that you could plug in there to get usable values.  You might decide that you want `Latitude 1 + Latitude 90 == Latitude 89` instance of `Latitude 1` (where the values "bounce" back after the reach the upper bound), or you can have them wrap around to the lower bound so that `Latitude 1 + Latitude 90 == Latitude -89`, or you can keep it how I have it here where it just adds or subtracts the bound until it's within range.  It's up to you which implementation is right for your use case.

Comment: That was exactely the kind of answer I wanted. Thank you (even if of course I still don't understand everything, but now I got my homework :)

Comment: @heltonbiker Well, what don't you understand?  Maybe I can help make things a bit more clear.

Comment: the `instance` part seems to solve one issue I am already having. I tried your code with
`main = do
    print $ Position {latitude=0, longitude=0, elevation=0}`
and got an error:
"    `No instance for (Num Longitude) arising from the literal '0'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Num Longitude)
    In the 'longitude' field of a record`"

Comment: @heltonbiker You'll have to fill in a similar `Num` instance for `Longitude` as well, you can simply copy/paste the one for `Latitude` and change all `Latitude`s to `Longitude`, and `mkLat` to `mkLong`.  I didn't give you absolutely everything =P

Comment: What’s the point of `normLat` and `normLong`? If the only two operations to make a `Latitude` or `Longitude`, `mkLat` and `mkLong`, normalize it, and all operations use `mkLat` and `mkLong`, surely, then, to code in another module, `normLat` and `normLong` would be equivalent to `id`?

Comment: @icktoofay you could eliminate those functions easily, but you shouldn't necessarily export them, and if you do I would document that they're for keeping a consistent API, not for construction.

Answer (score 6):

An alternative to using separate types for every field is to use encapsulation: create an abstract data type for your Positions, make all the fields private and only let users interact with positions using the public interface you provide.

```
module Position (
    Position, --export position type but not its constructor and field accessor.
    mkPosition, -- smart constructor for creating Positions
    foo -- your other public functions
) where 

-- Named fields and named conventions should be enough to
-- keep my code sane inside the module
data Position = Position {
  latitude :: Double,
  longitude :: Double,
  elevation :: Double
} deriving (Eq, Show)

mkPosition :: Double -> Double -> Double -> Position
mkPosition lat long elev =
   -- You can use this function to check invariants
   -- and guarantee only valid Positions are created.
```

The main advantage of doing this is that there is less type system boilerplate and the types you work with are simpler. As long as your library is small enough, you can keep all the functions in your head the naming conventions + testing should be enough to make your functions bug free and respecting the Position invariants.

See more on http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Smart_constructors

Comment: Well, in my example I am doing all the checking at runtime, without any fancy type system tricks. Its just plain old abstract data types, as seen in the 70s :)

Comment: The ADT approach is great because it allows you to abstract away from the representation of position. The latitude/longitude/elevation system naturally represents each position as an equivalence class rather than a single representation. You can avoid normalizing until it actually suits you. For example, you can perform a whole sequence of operations like "shift 0.02 north, shift 0.013 east, shift 12742 km down, shift 0.5 south" without normalizing, and only normalize when someone asks for a standard representation.

Comment: In fact, you don't even have to store it internally using latitude/longitude/elevation at all, if something else works better for your calculations.

Comment: @dfeuer That might actually be a better solution for high performance systems, since it would reduce the number of checks and the amount of arithmetic required to normalize the values.